# Issues using Dreamweaver Design view while editing a site that contains Smarty

Tags: smarty, dreamweaver

I setup a new site on dreamweaver and imported my site files in. I only did this since I wanted to play around with the design view, otherwise I just use notepad++. Anyways When I go into design view I can see the text of all my smarty tags and I don't see the design of the website. Is there a way to make the design view work properly so that my smarty code isn't shown as text and my website is shown correctly. Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! If this isn't possible should I just stick with editing my code in notepad++ or is dreamweaver better?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to Live View. Live view differs from the traditional Dreamweaver design view in that it provides a non-editable, more realistic rendering of what your page will look like in a browser.
When you switch to Live view from Design view, you are simply toggling the Design view between editable and “live”.

While Design view remains frozen once you enter Live view, Code view remains editable, so you can change your code, and then refresh Live view to see your changes take effect. When you’re in Live view, you have the additional option of viewing live code. Live Code view is like Live view in that it displays a version of the code that the browser is executing in order to render the page. Like Live view, Live Code view is a non-editable view.

An additional advantage of Live view is the ability to freeze JavaScript. You can refer to the following Wiki to know more: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WS753df6af718a350a-43cf1449133aea5253f-8000.html#WS16D4BD4B-0A17-44b9-95E9-ACC9795CE4F9

Regards,
Yalpi Shiva Prasad
Adobe Systems Incorporated.